# Mocha/Sinon - Unit testing promises in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, mocha.js

While learning **electron**, I decided I would also like to train testing techniques in JavaScript. I have following code:

```
const winston = require('winston');
const AutoLaunch = require('auto-launch');

const launchFunction = (mb) => {
  const autolaunch = new AutoLaunch();

  autolaunch
    .isEnabled()
    .then((isEnabled) => {
      if (isEnabled) {
        return;
      }
      autolaunch.enable();
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      winston.error(err);
    });
};
```

I would like to assert if **autolaunch.enabled()** is properly triggered under specific condition and I have a lot of problem with writing any test that won't force me to create stub with exact copy of function from **then()**. There is an option that maybe something is wrong in this design of this solution - I can (and would like to) change code to make it more testable. How should I cope with that problem without compromising code testability?

I use **mocha** and **sinon** but I don't feel really attached to those tools

Comment: Please take a look on [chai-as-promised](http://chaijs.com/plugins/chai-as-promised/) to test promises.

Answer (score 0):

I would try more functional approach. Wrap closure in question in function and test it separately.

```
function enableWhenNeeded(autolaunch, isEnabled) {
      if (isEnabled) {
        return;
      }
      autolaunch.enable();
}

autolaunch
    .isEnabled()
    .then(curry(enableWhenNeeded, autolaunch))
    .catch((err) => {
      winston.error(err);
    });
```

For purpose of the example, I made up function *curry()*, but I think there are at least thirty five JavaScript frameworks which provide one.

It is always a question is this code worth testing; if AutoLaunch is third party, why testing it?